# Issue Appending NSData to make .mts file from Wi-Fi Device

Tags: objective-c, wifi

I'm working on WI-Fi Camera device and fetching video file from the device..
**So im taking it from buffers and appending every NSData's  to make a whole NSData.**

How can i know if the stream is ended?
Finding out the lenght of response wont work for me.. any idea?